# Add space character to regular expression pattern [a-zA-Z]*

Tags: regex, validation, jsf, jsf-2

I'm using `<f:validateRegex pattern="[a-zA-Z]*"/>` for ensuring that entered values contain alphabet only, it is working fine but it is not allowing to take space in the string.
How can i incorporate space character in above pattern?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Simply add the space to the regex.

```
<f:validateRegex pattern="[a-zA-Z ]*"/>
```

If you wanted any whitespace, not just space, swap the space with `\s`.

```
<f:validateRegex pattern="[a-zA-Z\\s]*"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me.
It includes spaces in text at the start/ end of words.

```
/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/
```

Comment: The question is not about JavaScript.

Answer (score -3):

I'm used this [a-zA-Z_ ]* its working for me